Name of the movie? Crew thinks they're on a spaceship, but discover they're still on earth
I saw this live-action movie on German free TV at least 10 years ago (probably more). It definitely had "Voyager" in its name (at least, in the German dub's name, original might be entirely different) but had nothing to do with Star Trek.
It begins with a crew on a starship named Voyager. I cannot remember the reason of their mission (maybe supply delivery to distant planet, maybe to colonize a new planet), but they were headed away from earth.
I do not remember the next part, but something happens. The crew attempts to escape their craft, but two commit suicide (with some drug, I think).
Two make it out, but then find themselves in a guarded bunker. They are able to overcome the guard. Climbing out of the bunker, they see a destroyed city and conclude they are on earth.
What I saw ends there - but it seemed like it was supposed to be a 2-parter. Only I never saw the second part. I believe it to be a production from an English-speaking country (maybe involving Canada or Australia), but I cannot remember. The movie was in color and the look was that of a 90s production, at the earliest late 80s.
So my questions: What's the name of that movie and does a second part exist?

It sounds more like an episode of the newer Twilight Zone or something similar from TV (I know there was a couple of series along this line in the '90s to early 2000's).

@Paulster2 I think you're right. It sounds familiar to me as well.

"I Shot an Arrow Into the Air" has a similar ending, but it's from the old series. And maybe this will help, a2715187: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarthAllAlong

Reminds me of this episode of The Outer Limits http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667929/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_42

According to a similar question asked on the SF&F SE, this could be the 1965 BBC adaptation of J. G. Ballard's "Thirteen to Centaurus".

Star Quest (1994)
After being cryogenically suspended for almost a century, eight astronauts awaken to find that nuclear destruction has decimated earth and the human race. 
